# Add try to pdo execute

Tags: php, pdo

Code below adds data in db

```
    $sth = $this->db->prepare('UPDATE `adwords_clients_google` set status = 2');
    $sth->execute();
    $sth = null;  


    $sth = $this->db->prepare('
        INSERT INTO
            `adwords_clients_google`
            (`client_foreign_id`, `status`, `client_name`, `client_currency`)
        VALUES
            (:id, 1, :name, :currency)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
            `status` = VALUES(`status`),
            `client_name` = VALUES(`client_name`),
            `client_currency` = VALUES(`client_currency`)
    ');
    $sth->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $sth->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $sth->bindParam(':currency', $currency);
    foreach($accounts as $account) {
        $id = $account->customerId;
        $name = $account->name;
        $currency = $account->currencyCode;
        $sth->execute();         
    }
```

and I would like to add `try` here, something like

```
        try {
        if ($sth->execute()) {
            helper::putToLog('ok queryCampaignArr, inserted rows: ' . $sth->rowCount());
        } else {
            helper::putToLog('not ok', true);
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        helper::putToLog($sth->debugDumpParams(), true);
        helper::putToLog("ERROR: ".$ex->getMessage(), true);
    }
```

but i don't know should I add it for every row? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PDO for connecting DB then use PDOException   class to handle the exception.

```
try {
    if ($sth->execute()) {
        helper::putToLog('ok queryCampaignArr, inserted rows: ' . $sth->rowCount());
    } else {
        helper::putToLog('not ok', true);
    }
} catch (PDOException  $ex) {
    $Exception->getMessage(); // Error message
   (int)$Exception->getCode(); // Error Code
}
```

Comment: it's not my question. I asked how to use `try` within `foreach`